# Coxeter Isometry groups whose center has torsion

Tags: co.combinatorics, dg.differential-geometry, coxeter-groups

I'm looking for examples of Riemannian manifolds M of dimension $\geq 2$ such that the isometry group $Isom(M)$ contains as subgroup a finite Coxeter group $G$ such that $Tor(Z(G))$, the torsion group of the center of $G$, contains an element of order $\geq 3$.

Comment: The center of a finite Coxeter group never contains an element of order $\ge 3$ (http://www.m-hikari.com/imf/imf-2013/29-32-2013/zhangxigouIMF29-32-2013.pdf).

Comment: @Qiaochu: I'm surprised you refer to a paper from 2013 for a fact which was certainly well known before (see e.g. the reference that Max gave in his answer). I'm even more surprised that such papers are getting published...

Comment: No wonder I was having a hard time finding such an example :O) Many thanks!

Comment: @Tom: it was just the first reference I could find. Googling is faster than looking things up in Humphreys...

Comment: What about when $G$ is a finite group given by the quotient of a Coxeter group? Still the center never contains elements of order $\geq 3$?

Comment: The center of a quotient of a finite Coxeter group is still a 2-group. Again, you can reduce to the irreducible case. For $A_n$, the Weyl group is a symmetric group and the only non-trivial quotient has order 2. For the other families, the number of quotients also is rather limited, and I am pretty sure one can quickly rule out all cases (in fact I just verified this for irreducible spherical Dynkin diagrams up to rank 7). My guess is that his holds in fact for arbitrary (even infinite) Coxeter groups, but I didn't think much about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such a thing cannot exist, as the center of a Coxeter group $(W,S)$ is always an elementary abelian 2-groups.

Indeed, it is easy to reduce to the irreducible case, that is: If $S=S_1\cup \ldots S_k$ is a decomposition of $S$ into irreducible components, then $W= \langle S \rangle \cong \langle S_1 \rangle \times \cdots \times \langle S_k \rangle$, hence
  $Z(W) = Z(\langle S \rangle) \cong Z(\langle S_1 \rangle) \times \cdots \times Z(\langle S_k \rangle)$.

Now, for an irreducible Coxeter group $(W,S)$, if $W$ is infinite then its center is always trivial, and if $W$ is finite, it can be trivial or of order 2 (see e.g. exercise 1 in Section 6.3 of "Reflection Groups and Coxeter Groups" by James E. Humphreys. (There are perhaps better, and certainly older references for this, but I'll leave it to others to dig those up).

Comment: No wonder I was having a hard time finding such an example :O) Many thanks Max!